# Getting fieldname of any ckeditor in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, typo3

I'm loading my own JavaScript into the TYPO3 backend and reading the content of any ckEditor available.

Now I need fieldname, tablename und uid of the current edited record. The last two information I get via the data-attributes of the link with class "t3js-contextmenutrigger", which is always on bottom right of the record seen as the uid of the record. 
The fieldname I try to get very complicated from some other fields, until now not sucessfull.

Generally I do not like that way. I would prefer to have these informations somewhere else, maybe in an wrap of the ckEditor or as in an JavaScript Object which is loaded with the ckEditor.

How could that be possible or is there any other idea to get it in a clean way?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a better solution by requiring ckeditor module. Example:

```
define(['jquery','ckeditor'], function($, CkEditor) {
    var myObject = {};

    myObject.initialize = function() {
        console.log(CkEditor.instances,':51');
    };

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(myObject.initialize);
    });
});
```